how to choose html class for webscraping
Hi I want to pull all the comments, I can't do it, can you help me, my knowledge of html is weak and I don't know which class to take I would be very grateful if you could help me
those who understand webscraping and want to help me can write
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

url = "https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/EURUSD%3DX/community"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/124.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}

try:
    # Web sayfasını al
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    response.raise_for_status()  # HTTP hatalarını kontrol et

    html_content = response.text

    # BeautifulSoup kullanarak HTML içeriğini işle
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html_content, "html.parser")

    # İlgili div öğesini seç
  #  element = soup.find("div", class_="break-words leading-5")
   #
    element = soup.find("li", class_="spcv_list-item")

    if element:
        # Öğenin içeriğini al
        metin = element.get_text(strip=True)
        print(metin)
        df = pd.DataFrame([metin], columns=['Metin'])

        # DataFrame'i bir Excel dosyasına yaz
        df.to_excel('alibey.xlsx', index=False)
    else:
        print("İlgili öğe bulunamadı.")

except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print("HTTP isteği sırasında bir hata oluştu:", e)

except Exception as e:
    print("Bir hata oluştu:", e)


